# What is the difference between Visual C++ 2010 and the Express version?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What are the differences between Visual Studio C++ and the Express edition of the same?

Comment: This is not a c++ question ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dannawi/archive/2010/01/29/visual-studio-2010-datasheet-available-for-download.aspx

Comment: Just because Visual Studio is an `IDE` with c++ support, it doesn't mean you should use the `c++` tag!

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: What does that page say about _Express_?

Comment: How on earth is this off-topic?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Doesn't it compare Express too? The image is low quality, viewed it a second time, I still can't tell :D ...

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: It's not illegible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No offense, but I didn't say it's `off-topic`, I just removed the c++ tag ...

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: I am referring to the two off-topic close votes. Apparently two people feel that Visual Studio is not a "tool used primarily for programming".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I never vote to close :D. Changing the tags is a much better approach to such questions!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, maybe they consider VS a tool of mass destruction? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, my rep isn't high enough to close questions =/

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: I never said that you had anything to do with it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please don't bump old comments , I already knew that :)

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: 45 minutes is not old!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm on *instant response* mode! Spamming refresh for notifications hell yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia [tells us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express):

> **Visual C++ Express IDE does not have out-of-box support for compiling 64-bit applications**. An x64 cross-compiler (Cl.exe) is supplied with the full version Windows SDK (available free of charge, as a separate download). Integration of 64-bit compilers to the Visual C++ 2008 Express is possible, but remains cumbersome. Visual C++ Express 2010 supports straightforward integration but still does not come with a built-in 64-bit compiler. Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop, the successor of Visual C++ Express, has built-in support for developing 64-bit desktop applications.
>
> Other limitations of Visual C++ Express include:
>
> - **Lack of a resource editor**, which is available in commercial editions of Visual Studio.
> - **No profiling support**
> - **No support for OpenMP**
> - **No support for add-ins or IDE macros**
> - **Lack of support for attaching the debugger to a running process** (2005 and 2008 only)
> - **No option for crash dump generation**

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Express supports OpenMP (though 2010 does not).  I use it regularly.

Comment: @redrum: Yes, this is about Visual C++ Express 2010. They renamed it to Visual Studio Express for 2012. Very confusing of course since, in the commercial project, Visual C++ is already a subset of Visual Studio.